# How to update a df based in a list. Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the next df:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'car' :'audi','id':'ab','year':2001,'wheel':4},
        {'car' :'honda','id':'aa','year':2002,'wheel':15},
        {'car' :'tesla','id':'aaa','year':2003,'wheel':5}]

keys=['a','aa','aaa','avaa','2ffa']
```

| Car | ID | Year | Status | Wheels |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Audi | ab | 2001 | OK | 4 |
| Honda | baaa | 2002 | OK | 4 |
| Tesla | aaa | 2003 | OK | 4 |
| Tesla | avaa | 2023 | OK | 4 |

So, let's image the next situation: The IDs in the keys list are defective, thus, I have to update the 'Status' column with 'Defective' instead 'Ok' in the appropriate cases.

How can I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) combined with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.loc[df['id'].isin(keys), 'Status'] = 'Defective'
```

Updated `df`:

```
     car   id  year  wheel     Status
0   audi   ab  2001      4        NaN
1  honda   aa  2002     15  Defective
2  tesla  aaa  2003      5  Defective
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [220]: data = [{'car' :'audi','id':'ab','year':2001,'wheel':4},
     ...:         {'car' :'honda','id':'aa','year':2002,'wheel':15},
     ...:         {'car' :'tesla','id':'aaa','year':2003,'wheel':5}]
     ...:
     ...: keys=['a','aa','aaa','avaa','2ffa']
     ...:

In [221]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [222]: df
Out[222]:
     car   id  year  wheel
0   audi   ab  2001      4
1  honda   aa  2002     15
2  tesla  aaa  2003      5

In [223]: df['status'] = "OK"

In [224]: df
Out[224]:
     car   id  year  wheel status
0   audi   ab  2001      4     OK
1  honda   aa  2002     15     OK
2  tesla  aaa  2003      5     OK


In [225]: for k in keys:
     ...:     df.loc[df.id==k, 'status'] = "Defective"
     ...:

In [226]: df
Out[226]:
     car   id  year  wheel     status
0   audi   ab  2001      4         OK
1  honda   aa  2002     15  Defective
2  tesla  aaa  2003      5  Defective
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where` with `isin`:

```
df['Status'] = np.where(df['id'].isin(keys), 'Defective', 'OK')
print(df)

# Output
     car   id  year  wheel     Status
0   audi   ab  2001      4         OK
1  honda   aa  2002     15  Defective
2  tesla  aaa  2003      5  Defective
```